# GWT with Spring Security Caching Issue on GWT Page

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

I find this kind of odd I haven't been able to find any information on someone with a similar issue. Anyway, I've integrated Spring Security with GWT, and it appears to work correctly...for the most part. I'm having a caching issue with the main html page in IE and Chrome.

I've separated out Spring Security login to a login.jsp that redirects to my Application.html page (the GWT page), and when I first start the app and access the page, it appears to be working fine in all browsers. I get directed to the login page, because I'm not authenticated.

The issue is that in Chrome or IE, if i close the browser after a successful login, and directly browse back to that Application.html URL, it still renders as if I'm authenticated. I look in my console, and the log statements for spring security verify I am not authenticated. The moment i hit f5 to refresh the page, I get directed back to the login.jsp url.

I'm lead to believe this is some caching issue because when I close the browser and reopen to the html page, even though it renders like I'm logged in, the console log statements say I'm not, and if I run in debug mode, the OnModuleLoad() in Application.java never gets hit.

Finally, this appears to work properly in firefox...If anyone has seen this issue or has any advice of where I need to look to fix, I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problems with a web app that I've been working on.  I attempted to prevent the browser from caching the page by adding these tags to the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Unfortunately, this wasn't enough to prevent caching for all browsers.  I finally ended up converting the page to a JSP page and adding these statements to the top:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in Firefox, Chrome or Safari since I made the change.  I haven't tested the page with Internet Explorer yet.